# Twilio Paginate Video Tracks

Tags: twilio, video-streaming, twilio-video

We are currently using Twilio Video to enable users to make group video calls, where the calls adopt a grid-style view)

I've been looking for a way to paginate through pages of video tracks. The idea here is we only show the first 12 video tracks, and let the user paginate through sets of 12 video tracks. This functionality resembles Zoom when a video call surpasses a certain number of participants.

The ideal way to accomplish this (it seems) is to set maxTracks=12 when connecting, and then use the Track Priority API to lower the priority of the currently shown video tracks and increase the priority of the next page of video tracks.

Is this correct? Is there better ways to accomplish this?

Another idea was to use the Track Subscriptions API, but this requires us to move control server-side, which doesn't seem ideal for such a use case.

Comment: Yes, considering a similar approach for the project I am working on. What did you end up doing?

Comment: Ended up going with the suggested implementation with Track Priority API. Works quite well, its very responsive and video feeds are changed almost instantly.

We simoultaneously setup the Track Subscriptions API to support "breakout rooms". So within a single Twilio room, we can support breakout rooms by controlling track subscriptions on the backend, and then using Track Priority API on frontend to paginage between streams within the breakout room.